# MS Teams Unable to subscribe to Build Complete - Something went wrong, please try again later

Tags: azure-pipelines, microsoft-teams

In MS Teams, when trying to add a subscription for the event 'Build completed' for pipleline through 'Add Subscription' by giving the command *@Azure Pipleline subscription*, it come up with the message **Something went wrong, please try again later**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Neeraj

[image: Error]

Comment: Could you please try it in web browser and check what console error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue and is being tracked at https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Microsoft-Teams-Azure-Pipelines-app-Som/1534392?space=21&entry=problem

Answer (score 0):

We experience the same in the last 3 days, from teams over browser as well.

Comment: Could you please share what console error you are getting?

Comment: Same as mentioned in the title - "Something went wrong, please try again later". all used to work until 3-4 days ago

Comment: Thanks @Prasad-MSFT for getting back and sorry for the late reply. Below cropped message is been pasted from the browser. 

` 0.2-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114 Error: [BotCardFactory::createCard()] Failed in creation due to wrong card payload. Error = TypeError: e.replace is not a function

    at new t (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.2-app.min-5b6648e.js:1:4321592)
    at t.createCard (https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/hashed/3.2-app.min-5b6648e.js:1:4325206)`

Comment: Thanks for notifying us of the issue. We have raised a bug and will share any updates if the issue gets fixed.